# Override @Component from dependency

Tags: spring-boot

Let's say I have a Base project that I'll use as dependency in other projects. In this Base project I have a component that I want to make customizable. To simplify let's call it Tools. The Base project is making use of Tools in different classes.
Is it possible to override the methods from Tools component in a new project and make Base use the overrided methods?

Sorry if this is a basic question but I didn't find anything about this.

Comment: Think you would need to make event based code for that with event handlers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been some time, but i would like to share a really simple way to do it. I could not believe how simple it is.

Just extend the component you want to override, and add @Primary in it.

```
@Component
public class Parent {

@Primary
@Component
public class Child extends Parent {
```

Now, your app will use Child instead of Parent where Parent was @Autowired

Answer (score 1):

If you scanned the original package for original component bean, stop to scan the package and extend it yourself and scan the package you newly implemented. It's should work. Otherwords, you can define a `BeanPostProcessor` and replace it to yours. Both should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, the BeanPostProcessor  worked to replace the Component.